# How can be an icon set on the border of the react-bootstrap-table2

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

Trying to add a simple dot right on the end of the row in react-bootstrap-table but with no luck. My icon is in the last column in the row.

Icon is set in a div in an blueDotFormatter in a dummy field

```
   {
        dataField: 'blueDot',
        isDummyField: true,
        formatter: blueDotFormatter,
        headerStyle: (colum, colIndex) => {
            return {
                width: '1%',
                paddingRight: '0',
                marginRight: '0'
            };
        }
```

td's style is always overriding my style and i can not set the icon straight on the border of the row.

```
const blueDotFormatter = () => {

    return (
        <div className={"blue-dot blue-dot-"}>
            <img alt="image" src={blueDotIcon}/>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for that - setting the width for 0.8% and even 0.89% makes the image go to the border.